# How to name a company's primary app package

Tags: android, naming-conventions

I'm writing an app for a company, where the app will simply be known as <Company>'s app.

What is the best industry practice for how I should name the package, then?

The options I've been thinking of are:

- `com.company.app` seems kind of strange because obviously it's an app.
- `com.company` seems strange because it's "missing" the last token.
- `com.company.company` seems redundant.

I'm leaning towards `com.company` but wanted some input from people with experience writing apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.company.app` is better than others. Here `com` is domain. It should be your company website or not. `company for company name. and`app` for application name.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the best variant is `com.<companyname>.<appname>`

**EDIT 1**

If there is no app name you can use

```
com.companyname.android
```

Comment: The question is what to do when there is no `appname` - since this is just "the company's app" and not "the X app, made by company."

Comment: @configurator see edit 1

Answer (score 1):

you can name package in different ways. One of preferred ways is **com.companyName.appName**

Comment: The question is what to do when there is no `appName` - since this is just "the company's app" and not "the X app, made by company."

Comment: Then you have to name it as you like. May be if company Name is CompanyName then name package like com.company.name. Or something like that. It's completely your choice.

Answer (score 1):

if [company] equals [name app] you can use this name

**use this android**   com.[company].android

**use this for ios**   com.[company].ios

example : com.instgaram.andoird

else

**use this android**   com.[company].android.[name app]

**use this for ios**   com.[company].ios.[name app]

example : com.google.android.talk or com.google.android.gm